# Is this the right place to ask about clutter/home organizing?

Tags: discussion

It's a new year and I am about to start tackling removing old toys to make way for the new. I came to stack exchange looking for a site dedicated to home issues. The only sites I can think of that would tackle "clutter busting" is Lifehacks or Parenting. Am I on the right site? I've searched for questions discussing "clutter" but can't find. Do you guys have a policy on clutter-related questions?

If you already have a question that has been posed about purging the old to make way for the new, please direct me to it/them. Thx.

ps - sorry, accidentally posted this on the main page; meant to post in Meta.

Comment: Not unless it requires a hack. If you can just use conventional methods, or that's what you're looking for, this is the wrong site for you.

Answer (score 5):

Like J. Musser said in [a comment](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1324/is-this-the-right-place-to-ask-about-clutter-home-organizing#comment1907_1324), this site takes pretty much any question, so long as it's a question that is seeking a hack.

I don't see why home organization should be any different; however, please note that when asking, you should present the conventional method(s), and explain why those approaches don't cut it. Once you've done that, the question is on-topic here.

The only other site that I can think of that might take your questions is [Productivity](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/), but since I haven't ever looked at their site, I can't know for sure. FWIW, they do have an [organization tag](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organization); but then again, [so do we](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organization).

Good luck with your "clutter busting"! :)